# Passar várias variáveis em função Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

*PERGUNTA REFEITA PARA FACILITAR O EXEMPLO*

Tenho os seguintes inputs em um HTML (vou mostrar 3, mas a situação real são 20):

```
          <tr>
              <td>Digite o código:</td>
              <td><input type = "text" id="cod_item" name = "cod_item" size = 10 maxlength =5 placeholder="Código" onChange="getPeca();">
                  <input type = "text" id="desc_item_1" name = "desc_item_1" size = 30 maxlength =30 placeholder="Descrição">
                  <input type = "text" id="qtde_item_1" name = "qtde_item_1" size = 5 maxlength =5 placeholder="Qtde"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>Digite o código:</td>
              <td><input type = "text" id="cod_item_2" name = "cod_item_2" size = 10 maxlength =5 placeholder="Código">
                  <input type = "text" id="desc_item_2" name = "desc_item_2" size = 30 maxlength =30 placeholder="Descrição">
                  <input type = "text" id="qtde_item_2" name = "qtde_item_2" size = 5 maxlength =5 placeholder="Qtde"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>Digite o código:</td>
              <td><input type = "text" id="cod_item_3" name = "cod_item_3" size = 10 maxlength =5 placeholder="Código">
                  <input type = "text" id="desc_item_2" name = "desc_item_2" size = 30 maxlength =30 placeholder="Descrição">
                  <input type = "text" id="qtde_item_2" name = "qtde_item_2" size = 5 maxlength =5 placeholder="Qtde"></td>
          </tr>
```

A intenção é todos esses *cod_item* acessar a query abaixo e exibir a descrição no campo *desc_item*. Exemplo: O usuário digita o código e o Ajax retorna a descrição. Vai no campo 2 digita o código e aparece a descrição. O usuário pode digitar de 1 até 20.

```
$sqlRetorno = 'SELECT descricao from pecas WHERE
               cod_peccin = :codItem;';

$resRetorno = $conexao->prepare($sqlRetorno);
$resRetorno->execute(array(
    ':codItem' => $codItem,
));
$retornos = $resRetorno->fetchAll();
```

Na pergunta inicial tenho um Ajax mas que funciona apenas para um item. Nesse caso, como poderia fazer todos os campos fazerem a mesma consulta e retornarem independentemente a descrição do item digitado, sem ter que fazer um script para cada campo?

Comment: Queres enviar uma a uma ou todas no mesmo ajax? inseres uma peça por input, ou várias no mesmo input? No caso de serem vários inputs podes estão todos dentro da mesma tabela?

Comment: Os inputs estão todos na mesma página e os campos na tabela que vou guardar também. Insere um codigo por vez, mas todos os 20 estão no mesmo formulário.

Comment: vc pode fazer de passar todas as variaveis de uma vez só usando o serialize, com a sintaxe: nome_form.serialize();

Comment: vc não consegue fazer o ajax por jquery?

Comment: Pode me passar um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/  essa é uma forma de fazer ajax com jquery, mto mais facil do que com javascript puro

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ a documentação do serialize tbm...

Comment: Poxa Diego até tu tá usando *stack snippet* ("trecho de código") sem necessidade :/ - O stack snippet é obviamente usado para executar javascript, html e css, ou seja front-end, não tem porque usar stacksnippet para colocar php, c++, java, c#, isso nunca vai executar PHP. Se é só pra exibir código use a marcação normal ("amostra de código" ou ctrl+k).

Comment: Foi mal @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo vou tentar transformar essa tua ideia em uma solução, se der certo te aviso para responder a pergunta e ganhar a recompensa.

Comment: beleza! usando essa função post do jquery, vc faz ajax de um modo seguro e na passagem de parametros dessa função, vc usa só o serialize pra daí fazer como se fosse um submit na pagina, só que usando o ajax ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer fazer uma consulta ajax para cada campo de código que for alterado, e depois preencher o campo de descrição com o resultado da consulta.

> Estou reproduzindo apenas fragmentos do seu código, para ajudar a entender.

Primeiro vamos tratar seu `HTML`:

- padronize sua página para que cada campo tenha um número de identificação;
- insira o código do campo como argumento da função `getPeca()`;
- certifique-se de que cada conjunto possua um código único. Observe o exemplo:

```html
    <!-- Bloco do item 1 -->
    <tr>
        <td>Digite o código:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="cod_item_1" ... onChange="getPeca(1);">
            <input type="text" id="desc_item_1" ... >
            <input type="text" id="qtde_item_1" ... >
        </td>
    </tr>
```

No `Javascript`:

- primeiro crie o parâmetro que receberá o código (ex: `id_campo`);
- a variável do parâmetro será utilizada para concatenar o nome do campo, desta forma, `"cod_item_" + id_campo` será convertido em `cod_item_1` quando o `id_campo` for `1`;
- quando o servidor responder você pode utilizar o raciocínio do item anterior para preencher as informações do campo de descrição correspondente. Novamente, veja o exemplo:

```js
    function getPeca(id_campo) {
        ...
        // aqui o código do campo 'cod_item_{n}' é atribuido a 'codItem'
        var codItem = document.getElementById("cod_item_" + id_campo).value;

        ...
        xmlreq.open("GET", "ProcessaPecaEdicao.php?codItem=" + codItem, true);
        ...
        // durante o retorno do servidor
        if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {

            // Se o retorno for vazio basta gerar o alerta
            alert("Item inexistente! Cadastre antes");
        } else {

            // Aqui recebe os dados do processa.php, abre e aplica nos campos desejados
            var descricao = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);

            // Retornando apenas a descrição referente ao 'cod_item_{n}'.
            document.getElementById("desc_item_" + id_campo).value = descricao;

            document.getElementById("qtde_item_" + id_campo).focus();
        }

        ...
    }
```

Por fim, no código `PHP` (*ProcessaPecaEdicao.php*):

- este arquivo será chamado a cada vez que o campo código (*cod_item_{n}*) de um bloco do html for alterado;
- a consulta realizada aqui, pesquisa 1 código específico (*provavelmente uma chave primária, certo?*), e espera apenas 1 registro como resposta. Portanto você pode utilizar `fetch` ao invés de `fetchAll`;
- é uma boa prática você utilizar o `closeCursor` para liberar a conexão e permitir que novas consultas sejam realizadas. [*mais detalhes*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php)
- por ser chamado apenas para informar uma descrição de um código apenas (*codItem*), não tem muito o que programar. No exemplo abaixo, quando um código é recebido, a consulta é feita no banco e retorna a descrição do código informado;

```php
    // Dados do banco e controle de acesso
    include "js/conn.php";

    // Recebe variavel do index
    $codItem = $_GET["codItem"];

    //Inicia a consulta ao banco, com os dados informados pelo cliente.
    $sqlRetorno = 'SELECT descricao from pecas WHERE
                   cod_peccin = :codItem;';

    $resRetorno = $conexao->prepare($sqlRetorno);
    $resRetorno->execute(array(
        ':codItem' => $codItem,
    ));

    $retornos = $resRetorno->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $resRetorno->closeCursor();

    // Pequeno tratamento de erro do retorno.
    $retorno_tratado = ($retornos == false ? '' : $retornos['descricao']);

    // Retorna somente a descrição do código solicitado.
    echo json_encode($retorno_tratado);
```

Procurei manter seu código parecido com o original e tornar o mais claro possível, como você pode utilizar uma rotina `ajax` que atualizar diversos campos.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que não conseguia fazer. Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Ah, fiquei só com uma duvida aqui:         if (xmlreq.responseText == "") {

            // Se o retorno for vazio basta gerar o alerta
            alert("Item inexistente! Cadastre antes"); Ele não está entrando aqui, vai direto para o focus na quantidade, saberia me dizer o que poderia estar errando? No firebug o retorno aparece apenas *null*

Comment: @Diego, adicionei uma pequena correção de erro no código. Basicamente o `Fetch` retorna false quando não há registro no banco. Eu não havia tratado isso.. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Tem um problema aqui:

```
foreach ($retornos as $retorno) {

     $array = array('desc_item_1'=>$retorno['descricao']);
     echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Você está gerando vários json provavelmente, mas isso não funciona pois senão ficaria um resultado assim:

> {"desc_item_1": [...]}{"desc_item_1": [...]}{"desc_item_1": [...]}{"desc_item_1": [...]}{"desc_item_1": [...]}

O correto seria agrupar em array unico assim:

```
$retornos = $resRetorno->fetchAll();
$arrayAgrupada = array();

foreach ($retornos as $retorno) {
     $arrayAgrupada[] = array('desc_item_1'=>$retorno['descricao']);
}

echo json_encode($arrayAgrupada);
```

Agora sim você poderá usar o `JSON.parse`, seu resultado será algo como :

```
[
    {"desc_item_1": [...]},
    {"desc_item_1": [...]},
    {"desc_item_1": [...]},
    {"desc_item_1": [...]},
]
```

Eu vou ser sincero que não entendi o `desc_item_1`, talvez ele seja incremento ou é o ID do banco? Faça assim então:

```
$sqlRetorno = 'SELECT id, descricao from pecas WHERE
           cod_peccin = :codItem;';

$retornos = $resRetorno->fetchAll();
$arrayAgrupada = array();

foreach ($retornos as $retorno) {
     $arrayAgrupada[$retorno['id']] = $retorno['descricao'];
}

echo json_encode($arrayAgrupada);
```

Resultado:

```
{
   "1": "...",
   "2": "...",
   "4": "..."
}
```

E no Javascript isto:

```
var dados = JSON.parse(xmlreq.responseText);

ids.forEach(function (id) {
    var currentId = "desc_item_" + id;
    document.getElementById(currentId).value = dados[currentId];
});
```

Comment: Bom dia. Na verdade, o campo no banco é unico, usei essa nomenclatura de *desc_item_1* até o 20 nos inputs que gostaria de alimentar no html. Estou tentando entender a tua resposta, mas basicamente meu problema é que cada input que o usuario passaria o código é diferente, mas preciso usar a mesma query para todos, entendeu?

Comment: @Diego será um ajax pra cada campo?

Comment: Exatamente. Em uma solução que encontrei aqui, teria que criar 20 js, um para cada input, 20 PHP para processar a solicitação, declarar 20 funções no *body onload()*......não acredito que seja o correto isso

Comment: @Diego então a minha resposta é apenas uma requisição com js, eu não sei como é o seu SELECT, mas mudando ele poderá trazer todos 20 resultados com o código que postei, to no celular assim que conseguir eu edito a resposta, só me informa a query do SELECT

Comment: Ok! Esta no ProcesaPecaEdicao.php a query que uso e a variavel que passo, no caso uma apenas. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Diego vou admitir que teu código é bem confuso, sem querer ofender rs, cod_peccin é o ID de cada produto? Os inputs são gerados dinamicamente?

Comment: o cod_peccin é uma coluna que tem o codigo do item na tabela. Os inputs estou fazendo no braço, como não sei outra forma estou nomeando daquela forma codItem, codItem1, codItem2....

Comment: @Diego  é isso que tá confuso, cada input é um item da tabela ou não?

Comment: Não. Cada input tem que acessar a tabela com o valor que o usuario passar. A pesquisa será 20 vezes igual se o usuário inserir 20 itens.

Comment: @Diego se entendi a consulta é feita quando clica no input?

Comment: Exato!!! Pesquisa o item e traz a descrição.

Answer (score -1):

*Não dê o peixe, ensine a pescar*

1. Primeiro você vai precisar adicionar os 20 inputs no seu html, dando um id diferente para cada um deles

   2.Adicione query selectores para cada input no seu javascript
2. No seu código php adicione um **$_GET** para cada input diferente
3. Caso queira pegar esses dados passados e mandalos na query mysql, adicione:

```
$sqlRetorno = 'SELECT descricao from pecas WHERE
               cod_peccin = :codItem,
               cod_peccin2 = :codItem,
               cod_peccin = :codItem;';//adicione do 1 ao 20 em diante
```

Comment: Só uma dica `WHERE` não usa virgula `,`, tente usar `IN(..., ...,)` dentro de WHERE (se bem que eu não entendi a sua intenção na SELECT)

Comment: Como query selectores?

Comment: ja programei em php, nao me lembro se usa ou nao virgula, por isso fiz assim como exemplo